# How to import xml data to a fillable pdf file in linux?

Tags: pdf, xml

I have a fillable pdf template. Also have a xml file which is extracted from this fillable pdf file.

How can I export xml file from these fillable pdf files and also how can I create a normal pdf file from the the xml files or how can I import the xml files to these fillable xml files? I'm new in these things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt) to transform XML to PDF, or any other format. The procedure is to run the XML file through a XSLT Transformer using a stylesheet. The stylesheet can contain operations on XML nodes, as well as other content elements. An XSLT Transformer can be a stand-alone program, or built into an XML editor, and one is even integrated in your common browser.
You can find plenty of XSLT tutorials around the web.